# Digital Camera USB trigger

Tags: camera

Hey I have a couple of old digital cameras lying around and I was wondering if anyone knows of any software which allows you to take photos over the USB connection?

One is a Ricoh Caplio RR660
I will update with the other when I get home.

I'm pretty sure neither of them have manufacturer support for what I'm trying to do, I was hoping someone had some sort of hack they had seen around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cameras do allow you to initiate a remote grab via their USB connection, usually only with the manufacturer's software and usually only on Windows. It would help if you told us what digital cameras you have lying around.